# Default Boolean value in Java

Tags: java, boolean

I just want to know if there is a difference in Java between:

```
private boolean someValue;

private boolean someValue = false;
```

The second line maybe is just a time wasting?

**EDIT (SUMMARY):**

From the answers I found that there is almost no difference, but:

> *"Relying on such default values, however, is generally considered bad programming style."*

But there are some strong arguments not to do so - see accepted answer below.

**EDIT 2**

I found that in some cases `boolean` value **must be** initialized, otherwise the code **will not compile**:

```
boolean someValue;
if (someValue) { // Error here
     // Do something
}
```

In my NetBeans IDE I got the error - *"variable someValue might not have been initialized"*.

It's getting interesting.. :)

Comment: Actually, there is a tiny difference, but the end result is the same. You should prefer the first one, generally.

Comment: There is no difference; but if you use the second, then if later another programmer reviews your code and doesn't know about default values (it happens), then you will save him/her time if you explicitly specify `false`

Comment: @morgano: if another developer doesn't know about default values, then he will finally learn and know about them. It's a must-know.

Comment: @JBNizet In an ideal world, every one should be a professional and know what they are doing; unfortunately we live in the Earth and that doesn't happen, embrace it!

Comment: There is no problem in not knowing everything. There is a problem in refusing to learn. What's wrong in learning that Java fields have a well-defined default value? By your reasoning, you should also add a comment "this assigns false to the variable someValue", just in case the developer doesn't really understand what assignments are. I would agree with you if the code was relying on obscure rules such as `a += j++ - --b`, but default values are not at this level.

Comment: I think it's simple question - but look at the answers - I think lot's of people find it worthy.

Comment: This is a good question, and it deserves to be reopened. In Java, `boolean` and `Boolean` are very different beasts; the people who flagged **duplicate** are probably unaware of this. Unfortunately, they voted on a subject they did not study enough.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

All instance and class variables in Java are initialised with a [default value](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5):

> For type `boolean`, the default value is `false`.

So your two statements are functionally equivalent ***in a single-threaded application***.

Note however that `boolean b = false;` will lead to two write operations: `b` will first be assigned its default value `false` then it will be assigned its initial value (which happens to be `false` as well). This may have an importance in a multi-threaded context. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19939606/829571) of how explicitly setting the default value can introduce a data race.

> Relying on such default values, however, is generally considered bad programming style.

I would argue the opposite: explicitly setting default values is bad practice:

- it introduces unnecessary clutter
- it may introduce subtle concurrency issues

Comment: Yes, I agree, though official documents tells opposite...

Comment: It is good practise to set a value always, because of readability. Consider also the following: If you use Boolean instead of boolean, the default value is null.

Comment: @Hannes In the end, there is no definite answer: both are valid statements so which to use is a matter of taste and opinion... And We are talking about setting default value - if you want a Boolean to be false, then of course you should set it to false.

Comment: @assylias Totally right. But working with juniors you quickly forget about taste. You just want to minimize bugs. "Don't make me think"

Comment: I agree -- I detest code clutter. If you write code that duplicates what the compiler already did, I start to doubt you know your language. On the other hand, if you do rely on the compiler, then you better be right. If you __don't__ set a default when it is actually needed (local variables), then I know we have a problem.

Comment: @trillions please add your feedback to this answer as a comment, not an edit.  We don't want to be putting words into the original answerer's mouth.

Comment: @JAL, you right. thanks :)

Comment: @assylias, sorry that i was trying to modify your answer :). I was thinking it would be nice to point out that we don't need to initialize array too. such as boolean[] records = new boolean[5]; this will make sure all the booleans default as false itself.

Comment: @trillions I understand your point but it would not apply in this context - the question is asking about the difference between `int[] a;` and `int[] a = null` (the default value for arrays is null).

Answer (score 3):

If you didn't initialize it, it will be `false`. So there is no difference between them.

Answer (score 2):

The default value of `boolean` data type is `false` so we can say that there is no difference.

Comment: @Patrick Hofman thnks .

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, from:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

> It's not always necessary to assign a value when a field is declared.
>   Fields that are declared but not initialized will be set to a
>   reasonable default by the compiler. Generally speaking, this default
>   will be zero or null, depending on the data type. Relying on such
>   default values, however, is generally considered bad programming
>   style.

Comment: Hmm.. interesting note: *Relying on such default values, however, is generally considered bad programming style.*

Comment: I think this means you should initialize your variables at some stage, before they will be used. This mostly is being done in constructors, java compiler knows nothing about someValue purpose but its doing you a favor of setting it to known predictable value false.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare as a primitive i.e. `boolean`. The value will be **false** by default if it's an instance variable (or class variable).

If it's an instance variable `Boolean` it will be **null**.

*If it's declared within a method you will have to initialize it, or there will be a compiler error.*